# Load xml into mysql using values from another table

Tags: mysql, xml

I have a mysql database that I want to populate with xml data but I want this information to change depending on a value in another table.

The xml file looks as follows:

```
D<DATAROW num="1">
<FILM_DATE>20/04/2013</FILM_DATE> 
<FILM_NAME>DAYS OF THUNDER</FILM_NAME> 
<FILM_REVENUE>100</ FILM_REVENUE >
D<DATAROW num="2">
<FILM_DATE>21/04/2013</FILM_DATE> 
<FILM_NAME>TOP GUN</FILM_NAME> 
<FILM_REVENUE>120</ FILM_REVENUE > 
D<DATAROW num="3">
<FILM_DATE>20/04/2013</FILM_DATE> 
<FILM_NAME> MISSION IMPOSSIBLE </FILM_NAME> 
<FILM_REVENUE>100</ FILM_REVENUE >
```

For instance I want to load an xml file with film titles and dates into Film Details table

```
Load XML Local Infile ‘C:\film_details.xml
Into table film details
```

I don’t want to load the film name into the table Film Details but rather use the id from another table called Film Titles

```
+----+--------------------+
| ID |     Film Name      |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | Vanilla Sky        |
|  2 | Days of Thunder    |
|  3 | Top Gun            |
|  4 | Mission Impossible |
+----+--------------------+
```

I want the Film Details table to look as follows

```
+------------+-----------+---------+
|    Date    | Film Name | Revenue |
+------------+-----------+---------+
| 20/04/2013 |         2 |     100 |
| 21/04/2013 |         3 |     120 |
| 20/04/2013 |         4 |     100 |
+------------+-----------+---------+
```

Please note that the Film Name Column in Table Film Details is different from that in the XML (missing the “_”)

Is there a way to manipulate the xml data before it is inserted into the mysql database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a good idea if you load the XML file to a temporary table first. After that, a simple query should be enough to grab the code from the reference table.

This way you can solve both issues you have. the foreign key and the different field names.

Comment: Thanks Jose, I thought there may be a more effective way but this answers my question